# hook_menu() not available for ajax loaded links

Tags: 7, ajax, routes

I'm loading a datatable and its data into a panel, through ajax. Below is the link which can add the row(entry) to favorites. When I click the link, the jquery animation is executed properly but the hook_menu and it's callback function is not being executed. It looks like the hook_menu is not 'available'

This is the link

```
$link = array(
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => t('Favorite'),
    '#href' => 'favorite/' . $item->nid,
    '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('use-ajax', 'favorite_item_button'),
    ), 
);
```

And this is the hook_menu

```
function favorite_item_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['favorite/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'favorite item',
    'page callback' => 'favorite_item',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Do you see any mistakes? Am I doing something wrong, forgetting something?

Advice is much appreciated.

**Edit:**
- no php error logs
- no js error logs

tried: sitename.com/favorite/501 - got the error 'access denied'

Comment: did you clear Drupal cache?

Comment: yes I did, caching is not the problem. Also the JS is attached properly because the jquery animation works. More suggestions ? : )

Comment: when you add the link in the address bar what do you get e.g. `http://domain.com/favorite/54`

Comment: hmm, access denied is what I get. Does this mean I should add access arguments?

Comment: yes try to add `'access callback' => TRUE,` and clear Drupal cache

Comment: it works when I use the url and press enter. However, when I click on the link the menu and function is still not being called.

Comment: so when click on the menu, the link should load the page or fire ajax callback?

Comment: fire the callback (so the php function is executed without page refresh)

Comment: can you add `drupal_set_message('test');` in `favorite_item` function add see if you'll get the message

Comment: the menu_hook and the function to be called are working perfectly, without ajax. As said, if I go to sitename.com/favorite/501, the function is being executed and is working properly. When I click on the link (code in question), the hook_menu is not executed (so neither is the favorite_item function)

Comment: i think you need to add class `use-ajax` to menu item

Comment: tried, doesn't work :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8688/discussion-between-aboodred1-and-maarten-hartman)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `'access callback' => TRUE,` to your menu item.

Your menu callback should look like the following:

```
function favorite_item_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['favorite/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'favorite item',
    'page callback' => 'favorite_item',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```